# Remote Android phone's XMl file parsing?

Tags: android, xml

In my application,i have get the xmlfile data from the server and parse it.
But instead server,I want xml file will be saved on remote android phone.
1.how i connect and  parse another android phone's xml file.
2.Where should remote android phone has stored xmlfile on SDCard or where? thnks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.how i connect and parse another android phone's xml file.

There is nothing built into Android to allow you to "connect and parse another android phone's xml file". You are welcome to roll your own solution for this, but it will be very difficult for you to develop a reliable and secure solution.

> 2.Where should remote android phone has stored xmlfile on SDCard or where?

That will depend on what solution you develop that allows you to "connect and parse another android phone's xml file".

Comment: Sir..if my application is installed on remote android phone and xml file is created....then through which URL or IpAdreess can i connect to phone and get data..?suc if server connected then URL is like http://10.10.2.2/myform/abc.xml then how android phone's URL..

Comment: @DevalShah: "then through which URL or IpAdreess can i connect to phone and get data" -- there is no such URL. Android devices do not have servers open for anyone to connect to from remote locations.